# Do I need to repair the "plaster cement" around my drain?

Tags: shower, waterproofing, drainage

My linear shower drain clogged so I removed the drain grate and unclogged it. Now I have some spaces between the tile and the drain channel. This gap was filled with some sort of plaster cement but I broke some of it.

I would like to know how should I proceed in order to not have water infiltrating between tiles and shower drain.

Should I fill the gap with water proof cement and should I first scrape off all the existing cement or I can just add over the existing one and fill those gaps?

Comment: Providing pictures of what you're seeing is always helpful. You can simply [edit] your question, click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box, and it'll walk you through posting the pics.

Answer (score 1):

What you're calling "plaster cement" is, most likely, grout. It's the standard material that's used to fill the gaps between tiles the world over.

Grout doesn't waterproof the joint, but it does fill it, making it look nice, and does provide a minimum level of water resistance.

You will want to clean out any loose chunks of grout (may as well check the whole shower over while you're at it, you won't be able to buy grout in *that* small a container so you should have some to do other touchups), then push some grout into any gaps between the tiles and/or drain (there are tons of videos online about how to apply grout and probably more than a few questions here about it, too).

Once the grout has dried (check the instructions for the amount of time that'll take), you'll then want to apply **grout sealer**. This is the part that really does the waterproofing. Since the sealer is supposed to be reapplied periodically (check the instructions with yours to see what period they recommend), it's probably worth resealing all the grout in your shower at this point. Even if it was done recently, I doubt it would hurt to do it again.

Comment: May also want to pick up a **grout saw** to help remove any dubious spots before re-grouting.

Comment: Excellent point, sir!